# If we use the GLS estimation to handle paired data, why can't we use the Welch unpaired t-test as well?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, panel-data, generalized-estimating-equations, generalized-least-squares

Let's assume I have a paired data to analyse, for example from a longitudinal study.

A typical approach in biosciences is to use marginal (rather than conditional mixed) model, namely the linear model fit using the Generalized Least Square. The role of this model is to account for both heteroscedasticity (between timepoints) and dependency in data (within subjects).

It differs from the OLS with sandwich estimator in that the sandwich only accounts for heteroscedasticity, while the GLS accounts also for the dependency, also adjusting the model coefficients. Same does the GEE estimation.

But, when we fit the model, having, say, 10 subjects and 3 timepoints, we can observe it used 3x10=30 degrees of freedom. It says, that the model used all data only correcting the standard errors and slightly adjusting the coefficients.

Mixed model, at the same time, will use 10 degrees of freedom, showing, that it "detected" the pairs (or whole sequences) in data.

But, at the end of the day, the GLS is the gold standard of analyzing repeated data in experimental studies, especially using the Satterthwaite degrees of freedom.

And indeed, for 2 timepoints and compound symmetry, the paired t-test is equivalent (numerically) to the GLS.

Now, why can't we use the Welch-Satterthwaite test instead of paired t-test for the same? I checked, the results can vary a lot.

I don't provide data or code, because it's a general statistical question.

Is that because for inference the GLS calculates both variances and covariance between them, using them all, while the unpaired Welch t- test only uses 2 variances (without the covariance), only "corrected"?

If so, which approach is better in a single-arm experimental study with missing observations, where we compare the result against the baseline value?

A) to use separately data at each timepoint and then calculate the difference in means (knowing they differ in size), which is equivalent to use the Welch test and allows for unequal data size

B) to use difference (change scores) from baseline immediately, which is equivalent to paired t test and requires balanced data (to have pairs of them)?

Comment: @Dave That's not mine and I don't even understand Python. Can you keep my question? Mine is not about prediction, only about the inference and the approach to Welch vs. GLS. The linked post is by no means related to my question! If you delete it, I will ask one more time, because I need to know the answer to THIS question. The other question was posted 18 minutes ago, I couldn't post 2 questions one by one! It's not mine! I don't care about the other one as it doesn't answer my question. I don't even have reputation to join the other forum (50)!!!

Comment: I got mixed up and have retracted my close vote. I think I saw the capital G and got confused: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/600344/247274.

Comment: Thank you  @Dave